# How to add a toolbar at the bottom?

Tags: android, toolbar, bottomnavigationview

I'm trying to have my toolbar at the bottom. I already tried some tips but the toolbar rests at the top.

So: What do I have to change so my toolbar appears at the bottom?

If you need more code - there isn't much more - or other informations, just say so.

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity">
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.testingmapingmarker23.MapsActivity"
        />




   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the .java:

```
package com.example.testingmapingmarker23;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;



import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;



import static com.example.testingmapingmarker23.R.id.map;

public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        final Toolbar customToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);



    }




    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

    }





}
```

Styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <!--<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        &lt;!&ndash; Customize your theme here. &ndash;&gt;
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>-->



    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />

</resources>
```

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testingmapingmarker23">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <permission android:name="android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">



        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value=" API-Key (I removed mine)" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: 0
down vote
 

Android toolbar is the new Action Bar. It’s not bound to any activity, meaning it can be placed anywhere in the layout, is highly customize-able and can be used as an “Action Ba

Comment: Post your `styles.xml` file.

Comment: @aborocz I added it in my original post, kindly check it ou

Comment: Post your `AndroidManifest` as well. Thanks.

Comment: I've done it and just removed my API-Key.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Relative layout like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:id="@+id/map"
              android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_above="@+id/toolbar"
              tools:context="com.example.testingmapingmarker23.MapsActivity"
        />


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to Add navigationToolBar instead of ToolBar
[try this Link](http://www.truiton.com/2017/01/android-bottom-navigation-bar-example/)

See This

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_item_state_list"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_state_list"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_items"/>
```